# How to map two dataframe with output of overlapping items in new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
data = {
    'values': ['Cricket', 'Soccer', 'Football', 'Tennis', 'Badminton', 'Chess'],
    'gems': ['A1K, A2M, JA3, AN4', 'B1, A1, Bn2, B3', 'CD1, A1', 'KWS, KQM', 'JP, CVK', 'KF, GF']  
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df1

```
    values       gems
0   Cricket      A1K, A2M, JA3, AN4
1   Soccer       B1, A1, Bn2, B3
2   Football     CD1, A1
3   Tennis       KWS, KQM
4   Badminton    JP, CVK
5   Chess        KF, GF
```

second dataframe

```
data2 = {
    '1C': ['B1', 'K1', 'A1K', 'J1', 'A4'],
    '02C': ['Bn2', 'B3', 'JK', 'ZZ', 'ko'],
    '34C': ['KF', 'CD1', 'B3','ji', 'HU']
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

df2

```
    1C  02C 34C
0   B1  Bn2 KF
1   K1  B3  CD1
2   A1K JK  B3
3   J1  ZZ  ji
4   A4  ko  HU
```

I want check items in `df1['gems']` in each column of `df2` and represent their counts and overlapping items. The expected output is:

```
    values    gems                  1C  1CGroup   02C   02CGroup    34C 34CGroup
0   Cricket   A1K, A2M, JA3, AN4    1   A1K       0     NA          0   NA
1   Soccer    B1, A1, Bn2, B3       1   Bn2       2     Bn2, B3     1   B3
2   Football  CD1, A1               0   NA        0     NA          1   CD1
3   Tennis    KWS, KQM              0   NA        0     NA          0   NA
4   Badminton JP, CVK               0   NA        0     NA          0   NA
5   Chess     KF, GF                0   NA        0     NA          1   KF
```

Comment: 1. your output doesn't match your logic `B1` isn't in cricket, 2. where is your own code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first `str.split` and `explode` the column gems and `reset_index` to keep the original index. Then for each column of df2, `merge` with the exploded gems, `groupby` the original index and do both the `count` and the aggregation as you want
with `join`. `pd.concat` the merges for each column and join to your original df1. `fillna` the count columns with 0 as shown in the expected output.

```
# one row per gem used in the merge
df_ = df1['gems'].str.split(', ').explode().reset_index()

res = (
    df1.join( #can join to df1 as we keep the original index value
        pd.concat([df_.merge(df2[[col]], left_on='gems', right_on=col)
                      .groupby('index') # original index in df1
                      [col].agg(**{col: 'count', # do each aggregation
                                   f'{col}Group':lambda x: ', '.join(x)}) 
                   for col in df2.columns], # do it for each column of df2
                  axis=1))
        .fillna({col:0 for col in df2.columns}) #fill the count columns with 0
)
print(res)
      values                gems   1C 1CGroup  02C 02CGroup  34C 34CGroup
0    Cricket  A1K, A2M, JA3, AN4  1.0     A1K  0.0      NaN  0.0      NaN
1     Soccer     B1, A1, Bn2, B3  1.0      B1  2.0  Bn2, B3  1.0       B3
2   Football             CD1, A1  0.0     NaN  0.0      NaN  1.0      CD1
3     Tennis            KWS, KQM  0.0     NaN  0.0      NaN  0.0      NaN
4  Badminton             JP, CVK  0.0     NaN  0.0      NaN  0.0      NaN
5      Chess              KF, GF  0.0     NaN  0.0      NaN  1.0       KF
```

Comment: nice one, i did a `melt` and `merge` after the `explode` approach but felt like it was overly complex.

Answer (score 4):

First create a table of your groups:

```
df3 = (pd.merge(df1['gems'].str.split(',\s+').explode().reset_index(),
                df2.unstack().reset_index(level=0),
                left_on='gems', right_on=0, how='left'
               )
         .pivot_table(index='index',
                      columns=['level_0'],
                      values='gems',
                      aggfunc=list)
      )
```

output:

```
level_0        02C     1C    34C
index                           
0              NaN  [A1K]    NaN
1        [Bn2, B3]   [B1]   [B3]
2              NaN    NaN  [CD1]
5              NaN    NaN   [KF]
```

Then produce the counts and concatenate everything with the original table:

```
pd.concat([df1,
           pd.concat([df3.add_suffix('Group').applymap(lambda x: ','.join(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x),
                      df3.fillna('').applymap(len)],
                     axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
          ], axis=1)
```

output:

```
      values                gems  02C 02CGroup   1C 1CGroup  34C 34CGroup
0    Cricket  A1K, A2M, JA3, AN4  0.0      NaN  1.0     A1K  0.0      NaN
1     Soccer     B1, A1, Bn2, B3  2.0  Bn2, B3  1.0      B1  1.0       B3
2   Football             CD1, A1  0.0      NaN  0.0     NaN  1.0      CD1
3     Tennis            KWS, KQM  NaN      NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN
4  Badminton             JP, CVK  NaN      NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN
5      Chess              KF, GF  0.0      NaN  0.0     NaN  1.0       KF
```

edit: alternative for the string join and count

```
df3 = (pd.merge(df1['gems'].str.split(',\s+').explode().reset_index(),
                df2.unstack().reset_index(level=0),
                left_on='gems', right_on=0, how='left'
               )
         .pivot_table(index='index',
                      columns=['level_0'],
                      values='gems',
                      aggfunc=', '.join)
      )

pd.concat([df1,
           pd.concat([df3.add_suffix('Group'),
                      df3.applymap(lambda x: x.count(',')+1 if isinstance(x, str) else 0)],
                     axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
          ], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution with `findall`

For each column in `df2`, find all the occurrences of the column value in the gems column of `df1`, then `map` with `len` to count the occurrences and optionally `join` with `str.join`

```
for c in df2.columns:
    s = df1['gems'].str.findall('|'.join(df2[c]))

    df1[c] = s.map(len)
    df1[c + 'group'] = s.str.join(', ')
```

---

```
print(df1)

      values                gems  1C 1Cgroup  02C 02Cgroup  34C 34Cgroup
0    Cricket  A1K, A2M, JA3, AN4   1     A1K    0             0         
1     Soccer     B1, A1, Bn2, B3   1      B1    2  Bn2, B3    1       B3
2   Football             CD1, A1   0            0             1      CD1
3     Tennis            KWS, KQM   0            0             0         
4  Badminton             JP, CVK   0            0             0         
5      Chess              KF, GF   0            0             1       KF
```

Answer (score 2):

Worst solution using `set` and `apply`:

```
df1.gems =  df1.gems.str.split(', ')

df3 = df2.T
ix = 0

def func(row):
    global ix
    d = {}
    for idx, val in enumerate(df3.values):
        v = list(set(row) & set(val))
        d[df3.index[idx]] = ', '.join(v)
        d[f"{df3.index[idx]}Group"] = len(v) 
    ix = ix + 1
    return pd.Series(d)
res = pd.concat([df1,df1['gems'].apply(func)], axis=1)
```

**Concise solution:**

```
df1.gems =  df1.gems.str.split(', ')
for col in df2.columns:
    z = (zip(df1.gems, [df2[col].values] * len(df1)))
    res = ([', '.join(list(set(a).intersection(b))) for a, b in z])
    df1[col] = res
    df1[f"{col}Group"] = (list(map(lambda x: len(x.split(', ')) if x!='' else 0, res)))
```

**res:**

|  | values | gems | 1C | 1CGroup | 02C | 02CGroup | 34C | 34CGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Cricket | [A1K, A2M, JA3, AN4] | A1K | 1 |  | 0 |  | 0 |
| 1 | Soccer | [B1, A1, Bn2, B3] | B1 | 1 | B3, Bn2 | 2 | B3 | 1 |
| 2 | Football | [CD1, A1] |  | 0 |  | 0 | CD1 | 1 |
| 3 | Tennis | [KWS, KQM] |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 0 |
| 4 | Badminton | [JP, CVK] |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 0 |
| 5 | Chess | [KF, GF] |  | 0 |  | 0 | KF | 1 |